# issue with resolving activity for an intent - resolveActivityInfo()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, resolve

I am using resolveActivityInfo to determine if my app was set as a home launcher:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);   

    userHomePackage = intent.resolveActivityInfo(pm, 0).packageName;
    userHomeActivityClass = intent.resolveActivityInfo(pm, 0).name;     
currentHomeLauncherName = intent.resolveActivityInfo(pm, 0).loadLabel(pm).toString();
```

it works great on emulator and three android devices I have on hands.

Recently I started getting error reports from my users and error log shows that resolveActivityInfo is failing. This happens only on a few phones running on android 2.1 update 1 as I can see. I've received already many positive comments on my app and a few negative because of this issue.

Any advice what could be wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1224)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.resolveIntent(IPackageManager.java:1418)
    at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.resolveActivity(ApplicationContext.java:2046)
    at android.content.Intent.resolveActivityInfo(Intent.java:3790)
    at com.myapp.myappname.Launcher.setAsHomeApplicationBeforeFroyo(Launcher.java:336)
```

OR

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myappname/com.myapp.myappname.Launcher}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1864)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1224)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.resolveIntent(IPackageManager.java:1418)
    at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.resolveActivity(ApplicationContext.java:2046)
    at android.content.Intent.resolveActivityInfo(Intent.java:3790)
    at com.myapp.myappname.Launcher.showHomeChooserDialog(Launcher.java:141)
    at com.myapp.myappname.Launcher.showNextActivity(Launcher.java:122)
    at com.myapp.myappname.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:59)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1224)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.resolveIntent(IPackageManager.java:1418)
    at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.resolveActivity(ApplicationContext.java:2046)
    at android.content.Intent.resolveActivityInfo(Intent.java:3790)
    at com.myapp.myappname.Launcher.showHomeChooserDialog(Launcher.java:141)
```

Comment: The particular exception you are encountering does not appear to be from your code. Perhaps it is a buggy modded ROM that some people are using.

Comment: thanks for response! I have more reports now - a bit over 30 for the last two days - all of them came from samsung phones from different carriers and all running on android 2.1-update1. But I also have 5 star rate from users using the same phone models and running on 2.1 as well...go figure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did some research with android source and i tend to agree now with Commonsware that my code is right. I actually redesigned it 3 weeks ago to use packagemanager.resolveActivity instead of intent.resolveactivity:

```
this.pm = context.getPackageManager();

    try {
        Intent homeintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        homeintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        homeintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);// seems not needed here since This is a synonym for
                                // including
        // the CATEGORY_DEFAULT in your supplied Intent per doc

        this.resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity(homeintent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;

        userHomeLauncherPackage = activityInfo.packageName;
        userHomeLauncherClass = activityInfo.name;

        userHomeLauncherName = activityInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

        if (userHomeLauncherClass.contains("ResolverActivity"))
        userHomeLauncherName = "";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
```

It did not help so still getting these errors occasionally...

Based on the source code,

ComponentName Intent.resolveActivity (PackageManager pm)

or

ActivityInfo Intent.resolveActivityInfo (PackageManager pm, int flags)

call the same method defined in android.app.ContextImpl class:

ResolveInfo info = pm.resolveActivity(this, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)

and it is defined like:

```
        @Override
    public ResolveInfo resolveActivity(Intent intent, int flags) {
        try {
            return mPM.resolveIntent(
                intent,
                intent.resolveTypeIfNeeded(mContext.getContentResolver()),
                flags);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Package manager has died", e);
        }
    }
```

so at this point i came to conclusion that I cannot do anything about this :(

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem and have reached the same conclusion.  Did you report to Google?

Comment: I do not think we should blame google - this code works fine in emulator and I tried all versions of api. so it must be something with manufactures firmware.

Comment: This issue also happens on Nexus7 :`PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);`

Answer (score 4):

Kevin from TeslaCoil Software here. Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. This is what I'm using to get the Home component in my apps:

```
public static ComponentName getHomeComponent(PackageManager PM) {
    Intent home_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    home_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    home_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

    ComponentName cn = home_intent.resolveActivity(PM);
    if (cn == null)
        Log.v(TAG, "[Default] package:null");
    else
        Log.v(TAG, "[Default] package:" + cn.getPackageName() + " class:" + cn.getClassName());

    return cn;
}
```

resolveActivity doesn't normally return null, as it seems to return the resolver activity if there is no default set. But on some phones or something it might return null just to keep things interesting. Perhaps resolveActivityInfo calls resolveActivity but doesn't handle the null case properly.

Comment: thanks Kevin! intent.resolveActivity is pretty much as the same as intent.resolveActivityInfo and the error happens inside these methods so I cannot check result on null, since it fails before that. I am now using for 3 weeks pm.resolveActivity(homeintent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) instead but still got a few errors like that every day from phones running on 2.1. I guess it a bug in a firmware not mine